# Need an intuitive explanation of the solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been working to solve this question-"Suppose,we have two strings A and B of lengths 5 cm and 6 cm respectively.And,we have another piece of string C whose length is 4 cm.Now,we have to make the strings A and B equal in length by cutting the string C and adding it to A and B such that string C is completely used.Find what length of strings should be added to A and B ?"

I solved this question in this way,
Let the length of string added to A be "x" and the length of string added to B be "y".

Then,5+x=6+y

$$\implies x-y=1....(i) $$

And,$$\implies x+y=4..... (ii)$$

On adding (i) and (ii) we get,

$$\implies x=5/2=2.5 \space and \space y = 1.5 $$

So,i must say that i have gone on to solve this question blindly(without know exactly what really happens when i add those two equation (i) & (ii)).
*I want to know why adding those two equations can precisely divide 4 cm into such two parts which when added to A and B makes them equal(A=B)?*

I have another doubt,

After solving the question i get these answers- (2.5,1.5).
now what i want to know is that why can't there another set of number exist (X,Y) such that $$\implies X+Y=4\space and\space5+X=6+Y $$

(Why can't another set of number exist which can satisfy the demands of the question ?)

I will be thankful for help!
Note:I am a high school student and English is my second language.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: You really don't need to scream in all caps like that. It doesn't help much.

Comment: I have edited my question.please check it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphically, you could think about it as the intersection of two lines. 
You have  $$x-y = 1 \implies y =x-1\tag{1}$$ and $$x+y = 4 \implies y = 4-x\tag{2}$$

Evaluating $(1)$ and $(2)$ at a certain $x$ will give you the "height" of the function, this is, the $y$ value. If the lines are not parallel, then it's clear that at some point they are going to intersect. If they intersect, then $y$ value of both equations will be the same (for they are describing the same point). This is why we are subtracting the $y$ values, so that the distance between their "height" is zero. So then we can write $(1) - (2)$ as

$$y - y = 0 = 2x -5 \iff x = \frac{5}{2}$$

giving us our desired solution.

Why are there no other solutions? because two distinct lines cannot intersect at more than  one point (there are many Euclidean proofs for this) . If a your system of equations did not have a solution, then the lines would be parallel to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` sign means "the thing on the left and the thing on the right are the same".

Typically, what's written on the left and right look different, but the assertion that an equation is true means that you just have two different ways of writing the *same* thing.

So your two equations are saying: $x-y$ is the same thing as $1$, and $x+y$ is the same thing as $4$.

Consequently, if those assertions are true, then it's also true that $(x-y) + (x+y)$ is the same thing as $(1) + (4)$: that is, you have an equation

$$ (x-y) + (x+y) = 1 + 4 $$

This is the general philosophy of algebra: find a way to write the same thing in two different ways, but where one way tells you about something you want to know about and the other way is something you understand.

---

Note, incidentally, that you haven't proven that there is *actually a solution*. In fact, what your work does is to the very question you asked — from the assumption that $x$ and $y$ give a solution to the problem, you've proven that $x$ is the same thing as $2.5$, and that $y$ is the same thing as $1.5$; i,e, that $x=2.5$ and $y=1.5$.

You have to do some additional work to show that these values actually give a solution to the problem. (e.g. simply plugging those values into the problem to see that they work)

This point is something that is very commonly misunderstood.